# Nested facet search

Tags: solr

I have following documents in Solr:

```
(1) { date:"2013-01-01", person:"John",  activity:"swimming" }  // <-- watch out date/year
(2) { date:"2014-01-02", person:"John",  activity:"cycling"  }
(3) { date:"2014-01-03", person:"John",  activity:"jogging"  }
(4) { date:"2014-01-01", person:"Paul",  activity:"swimming" }
(5) { date:"2014-01-02", person:"Paul",  activity:"cycling"  }
(6) { date:"2014-01-03", person:"Paul",  activity:"jogging"  }
(7) { date:"2014-01-01", person:"Ringo", activity:"swimming" }
(8) { date:"2014-01-02", person:"Ringo", activity:"cycling"  }
(9) { date:"2014-01-03", person:"Ringo", activity:"climbing" }  // <-- watch out activity
```

Assume all fields as `indexed` and `stored`.

Now I want to find all persons which did `swimming` `AND` `cycling` but `NOT` `jogging` (all in `2014`). The correct answer of course should be `Ringo`. I think the solution will be a nested facet search, but I am not sure and I don't knwo how.

Comment: If this is a common query you should think about indexing the non-activities, as well. Like a field `inactivity: jogging`. Do as much work on the index side as possible, makes your query side faster and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: ok, I understand now... with 'swimming AND cycling' you mean the Lucene AND. Sure then this is not valid.

Then, how about this, you can can query for `activity:(swimming) AND date:[2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z TO 2014-12-31T23:59:59.999Z]`, and use the following facetting:
`facet=on&facet.query=activity:cycling&facet.query=activity:jogging` and just keep the values that are in cycling facet but not in jogging facet.

Needs a bit of client side code but should work?

Comment: Wouldn't this just give me back the documents 2,4,5,7,8 and 9? This is far away from the wanted answer `Ringo`...